# Python Auto Click bot not working and I cant figure out why

Tags: python-3.x, bots

I made a python 'aimbot' type program that looks for targets in the aim trainer and clicks on them. The problem is it clicks but not on the target and I'm pretty sure I did everything right. Here's the program:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

time.sleep(2)

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)


while keyboard.is_pressed('q')== False:

    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0,1080,1920))

    width, height = pic.size

    for x in range(0,width,5):
        for y in range(0,height,5):
            r,g,b = pic.getpixel((x,y))

            if g == 154:
                click(x,y)
                time.sleep(1)
                break
```

Comment: Try printing (or logging) the click location (x and y). Is it what you expect it to be? What do you expect it to be? Why is off?

Comment: oh thank you. There was too many of the same color and it couldn't pick one i guess